# Implementing IConsumerTokenManager in DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to use DotNetOpenAuth in my ASP.NET MVC application to interact with the LinkedIn API. To persist and retrieve tokens to/from my database I need to implement IConsumerTokenManager in my service layer. Currently I'm retrieving the token secrets for an access token (not a request token) like this:

```
public string GetTokenSecret(string token)
{
    // Retrieves token secret from database based on the user's username
    string tokenSecret = _db.LinkedInAccounts.GetTokenSecret(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    return tokenSecret;
}
```

This feels very dirty because I'm having to reference System.Web and HttpContext in my service layer. I really don't want to do this, but I'm having trouble determining another way to retrieve the access token. I could just retrieve it using the access token like so:

```
string tokenSecret = _db.LinkedInAccounts.GetTokenSecret(token);
```

But I'm not exactly sure if access tokens will be unique and how this will affect database performance when there are thousands of access tokens stored.

Is this second way the way to go, or is there a better alternative? I really don't want to have to reference System.Web in my service layer.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** If anyone faces a similar issue, I ended up injecting the username as a constructor parameter into my implementation of the IConsumerTokenManager using Ninject.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the secret based on the passed in token. Not the logged in username. An index set up for that column in your database should make the lookup fast. I suspect your current lookup by username would not be any faster anyway.